# How to loop a dynamic formula through a data.frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am a complete newbie in R and I got inserted into a project that requires a lot of R skills. Therefore and even though I am taking R classes, I am already looking  for a way to loop a percentage change formula  (T- (T-1))/T-1 over a data.frame for each company.

What the initial dataframe looks like.  Please note this is a sample
dataset, code would be then adapted to a nrow and ncolumn data.frame:

[image]

And the code to create this initial dataframe is:

```
company <- c("Aa", "Bb", "Cc", "Dd") 
sector <- c("B", "A", "E", "Z") 
lastmarketcap <- c(18, 4571, 122, 239) 
X200201 <- c(12, 4567, 121, 234) 
X200202 <- c(13, 4568, 121, 236) 
X200203 <- c(16, 4568, 122, 237) 
X200204 <- c(18, 4571, 122, 239) 

databasis <- data.frame(company, sector, lastmarketcap, X200201, X200202, X200203, X200204)
```

The final data.frame should look like:

[image]

In advance thanks for your help!

Comment: What happend to column `200201`?

Comment: your example data does not work. Its a convention in the whole programming world that variables don't start with a digit but rather a small letter.

Comment: Something like `indx <- grep("\\d{6,6}", names(databasis)) ; round(((databasis[tail(indx, -1)] - databasis[head(indx, -1)]) / databasis[head(indx, -1)]), 4) * 100` should be generic enough

Comment: @Robin_Hcp note my edit with a readable and general solution for however many columns you have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your column names are not syntactically valid. Here's a dataframe that works, and a way to do what you want:

The solution:

```
m <- data.matrix(databasis[-(1:3)])
new <- cbind(databasis[1:3], (m[,2:4] - m[,1:3])/m[,1:3])
new
#   company sector lastmarketcap           Q2          Q3           Q4
# 1      Aa      B            18 0.0833333333 0.230769231 0.1250000000
# 2      Bb      A          4571 0.0002189621 0.000000000 0.0006567426
# 3      Cc      E           122 0.0000000000 0.008264463 0.0000000000
# 4      Dd      Z           239 0.0085470085 0.004237288 0.0084388186
```

If you want to get clever and make a readable and general solution, define some simple functions first:

```
except_last <- function(m) m[,seq_len(ncol(m) - 1)]
except_first <- function(m) m[,seq.int(2, ncol(m))]
```

Then use that to subset:

```
new <- cbind(databasis[1:3], 
             (except_first(m) - except_last(m))/except_last(m))
# produces the same new as above
```

The above will work for however many years and quarters you might have.

The data:

```
company <- c("Aa", "Bb", "Cc", "Dd") 
sector <- c("B", "A", "E", "Z") 
lastmarketcap <- c(18, 4571, 122, 239) 
Q1 <- c(12, 4567, 121, 234) 
Q2 <- c(13, 4568, 121, 236) 
Q3 <- c(16, 4568, 122, 237) 
Q4 <- c(18, 4571, 122, 239) 

databasis <- data.frame(company = company, sector = sector, lastmarketcap = lastmarketcap, Q1 = Q1, Q2 = Q2, Q3 = Q3, Q4 = Q4)
```

Comment: `except_first(m)` is `tail(m,-1)` (or just `m[-1]`) and `except_last` is `head(m,-1)` (or `m[-length(m)]`), I wouldn't define functions just for those.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper in base r, those aren't doing the same thing.

Comment: oh right, I missed the comma, still, it's `m[,-1]` and `m[,-ncol(m)]`

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Good point, but renaming simple subsetting expressions still makes me feel like Hadley :p. See `everything()`, which is just `seq_along()`

Comment: Too each his own, but on one hand `everything()` is `seq_along(current_vars())` and is part of a family of functions, so you can make a case that it makes things clearer (though you may use `seq_along(.)` in  most cases I suppose), and on the other hand, as much as I like the hadleyverse, we'd be in trouble if a second guy came with new the same ambition or redoing 50% of base functions just changing default parameters ;). If it's just a local function to improve readability (though I don't think it does here) then why not.

Comment: And your functions are wrong :), you used `nrow` instead of `ncol`, and they'd be more efficient using negative indices.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Are negative integer indices more efficient in R than positive integer indices? I thought it was the other way around

Comment: I would expect negative indices to be very slightly less efficient, but the (all relative) expensive thing here is building the sequence.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167627/discussion-between-dan-hall-and-moody-mudskipper).